# Long layover in Narita, Japan

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork, japan

I am a Myanmar citizen and I have a US visa. When go back to Myanmar I have a long layover (about 20 hours) in Narita and I have to stay overnight there. Do I need transit visa? I am now in Dallas, Texas.

Comment: We get lots of such questions everyday. You can hope for a Shore Pass or apply for a transit visa to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Passengers with a passport and a confirmed onward ticket to
>     a third country within 72 hours can obtain a Shore Pass on
>     arrival if there are no connecting flights on the same
>     calendar day.

So you do **not** need a visa; rather, by presenting your passport and onward ticket, you can get a 72-hour entry stamp.

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that the Shore Pass is a privilege, not a right.  Consider applying for a transit visa if you want to be sure they'll let you out.

Comment: @jpatokal Even with a transit visa entry is never *guaranteed*

Comment: Of course not, but the odds are far higher.

Answer (score -1):

TIMATIC is incorrect. Shore Pass is provided only in emergency cases, so it's up to immigration officer. As you are from Myanmar he can decide it's too risky.

Narita airport is closed at night, you have to leave it. So you need a transit visa. If you have no transit visa, you may be forced to stay in guarded hotel paying for hotel and guards.

Comment: TIMATIC is **not** incorrect. The Shore pass facility used to be more limited in the past, but I've spoken to immigration at Narita about this last year and they confirmed the TIMATIC info.

Comment: In addition, while Narita is not a 24-hour airport, sleeping there overnight is OK. https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/tokyo_narita.htm

Comment: @jpatokal Not in the transit area though (that only works at Haneda and Osaka-Kansai)